# Get ListView custom friends from class extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm struggling with getting more than just one value from a custom made list.
I can get the "main" value out of it thanks to `getItem(int pos)`, but since I'm storing multiple values for one row (row meaning each `CustomList` in a `TableView`), I'd like to be able to get the corresponding values to the label I'm able to pull out.

I'm sure this is simpler than I'm making it out to be, so I'm hoping someone has done this before.

I've got a `CustomList` class,

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] labels;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    private final String[] identifier;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] labels, Integer[] imageId, String[] id) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, labels);
        this.context = context;
        this.labels = labels;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.identifier = id;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView idTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.identifier);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        txtTitle.setText(labels[position]);
        idTitle.setText(identifier[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        return rowView;
    }

    public String getKey(int position, int category) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView idTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.identifier);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        if (category == 1) {
            return idTitle.getText().toString();
        } else if (category == 2) {
            return "url:();";
        } else {
            return this.getItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: `getKey` is a tired, last attempt of getting values out of this `ListView/CustomList` data.
I can't for the love of it call that function in any way, shape or form.

Here's how I use this `CustomList`,

```
CustomList adapter = new
                    CustomList(MainActivity.this, urls, images, identifiers);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fairly straight forward, now later in the code - more specifically on a Button - I want to access the data stored in the List.
I do this by doing the following:

(This is where I bump into a mind bender)

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListAdapter table = listView.getAdapter();

for(int i = 0; i < table.getCount(); i++){
    Object row = table.getItem(i);
    Log.i("Test", row.toString());
}
```

What I get out of this is the `CustomList.labels[i]` value, which isn't all to odd seeing as I assume this invokes `getItem` of `ArrayAdapter`.

I tried doing a `@Override` on `getItem` as well but as it only takes one argument, that is `position`, I wasn't familiar enough with Java to get that working for me.

Any Idea how I could go about getting either the `imageId` or `identifier` variables from each row item of `listView1`?

In case you need the `list_single.xml` which is the layout of `listView1` (at least, that's my interpretation of what this file does), here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/identifier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case BaseAdapter is better choice than ArrayAdapter.

You can create your domain model with 3 fields in your case, define array of this models inside adapter and return them from getItem.

Example implementation:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView

In your case it would be something like this

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class DataObject {
        private final String label;
        private final Integer imageId;
        private final String identifier;

        public DataObject() {}

        public DataObject(String label, Integer imageId, String identifier) {
            this.label = label;
            this.imageId = imageId;
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public Integer getImageId() {
            return imageId;
        }

        public String getIdentifier() {
            return identifier;
        }
    }


    private Context context; //context
    private ArrayList<DataObject> items; //data source of the list adapter

    //public constructor
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataObject> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size(); //returns total of items in the list
    }

    @Override
    public DataObject getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position); //returns list item at the specified position
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate the layout for each list row
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);
        }

        // get current item to be displayed
        DataObject currentItem = getItem(position);

        // get the TextView for item name and item description
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView idTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.identifier);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        //sets the text for item name and item description from the current item object
        txtTitle.setText(currentItem.label);
        idTitle.setText(currentItem.identifier);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageId);

        // returns the view for the current row
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you still want to construct adapter from 3 arrays you can use additional constructor like this. But maybe better change something in data model.

```
public CustomList(Activity context,
                  String[] labels, Integer[] imageId, String[] id) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = new ArrayList(labels.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        this.items.add(new DataObject(labels[i], imageId[i], id[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can improve this solution using ViewHolder pattern https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder or RecyclerView

Comment: Literally one minute after asking a silly question I figured it out. This is probably a unessesary long way around setting this up, but here's how I did it: `ArrayList<CustomListAdapter.DataObject> itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomListAdapter.DataObject>(); CustomListAdapter moo = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemsArrayList); moo.getItem(0).getLabel();` - In case anyone wonders.

Comment: Ok no, I still don't know how to initialize this with actual values... How/Where do i put my initial `String[] labels` for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Java is object oriented. Make objects.

```
class DataObject {
    private final String label;
    private final Integer imageId;
    private final String identifier;

    public DataObject() {}
}
```

Use `public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<DataObject>{`

You can optionally store `DataObject[]` or better `List<DataObject>`, but getItem can now return the entire object, which then you get data from that.

You can use `adapter.add` to add data directly to the adapter / listview